# Trying to compare 2 lists on different sheets with conditional formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am adding a list of patients for the day onto a new sheet in an excel workbook every day.

I am wanting to have excel automatically highlight patients on today's list that were not on my list yesterday.

I tried using

```
=COUNTIF(Yesterday!$A$1:$A$100,Today!$A$1)
```

But this only works if the patients are on the same row in both lists. If a new patient is added, it throws the entire sheet off and highlights incorrectly.

Comment: You have to watch out for absolute/relative cell references. Try `=COUNTIF(Yesterday!$A$1:$A$100,Today!$A1)`